# Material won't show correctly on Blender object in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

I imported a Blender object in Unity without any textures or materials, if i try to apply a material to the imported object in Unity,
[the material won't show correctly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5yet.png) As you can see from the image, instead of showing the rocky material it just shows a grey color.

Comment: Have you correctly set the [UVs](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/UV_Map_Basics) in Blender?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have textures that arent showing up correctly then its possible that you need to uv-unwrap your object before importing to unity. Here is a youtube [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=scPSP_U858k) showing how its done. As long as you have a material slot in blender then there shouldnt be any issues with applying a new material from unity. When you import the file click on it from the file manager and view the settings in the inspector. You should see an option to override the material(s) with your own unity made ones, here is an image I found online for an example: [image]

Comment: Would also be helpful if you could post a screen shot of the object selected in the inspector window to see your import settings, this could be an easy fix

Comment: i tried to import the blender model in unity as a blender file with one material as placeholder but still didn't work. What import settings window should i make a screenshot of?

Comment: thats good! please mark that my answer worked so it can help others that stumble upon your question :)